# BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener: How to get context in onLocationChanged

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context, locationlistener

My problem is quite easy: I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that implements a `LocationListener`. The `LocationListener` needs the usual unimplemented methods and those are outside the `onReceive` of the `BroadcastReceiver`, so I have no context to use. The thing is that inside the `onLocationChanged` method (one of the `LocationListener` unimplemented ones) I have to call a method the must use context and I don't know how to get it.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        method(context);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {           
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {           
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a class level Context like below, and then use it.

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener 
    {

```
private Context context; 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
this.conext = context;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    method(context);       // Now you can use context
}
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {           
}
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
}
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {           
}
```

Comment: That's true. But does it really use the right context or it just gives me no error because I've declared the variable with "private Context context" that could even be empty. I mean since the onreceive it's called only when the broadcast is triggered and not as soon as I instantiate the class from outside this class are you sure that method(context) will get the context passed in the onReceive methond and not just a null one obtained by the declaration "private Context context"?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a BroadcastReceiver that implements a LocationListener.

If this `BroadcastReceiver` is registered via the manifest, having it be a `LocationListener` is pointless, as your process can be terminated milliseconds after `onReceive()` returns.

> I have to call a method the must use context and I don't know how to get it

If you are using `registerReceiver()` to set up this `BroadcastReceiver`, and for some reason it makes sense for you to also have it be a `LocationListener`, your `Context` is whatever called `registerReceiver()` (`Activity` or `Service`).

Comment: I have many methods inside this broadcastreceiver and yes I've registered it via the manifest. When the onReceive is triggered the process has to be teminated as soon as it does what is inside the onReceive. So that's fine. In one of the method I have the requestLocationUpdates and that's why I need the LocationListener and the context (I need the context because of   LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
)

Comment: @user2911015: "When the onReceive is triggered the process has to be teminated as soon as it does what is inside the onReceive. So that's fine" -- then there is no point in your calling `requestLocationUpdates()`.